# Exporting PDF with table of contents hyperlinks in Microsoft Word 2011?

Tags: pdf, preview, file-conversion, ms-office, skim

When I save a document in Word 2011 to PDF, the hyperlinks in the documents' table of contents and other cross-reference links aren't clickable. That is in the PDF document when I click on a table of contents item in Preview or Skim, it doesn't jump to the page containing the content for that item.

In contrast when I save the same document to PDF in Word 2010 (the Windows version), the PDF table of contents hyperlinks are created and works fine both on Windows (Acrobat Reader) and on the Mac (Preview and Skim).

Is there a configuration option that I'm missing in Word 2011? How to get Word 2011 to generate the table of contents PDF links? I've tried printing the document to PDF but it didn't work.

Comment: YMMV, but try Print > PDF > [Save as Adobe PDF](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/cant-print-pdfs-mac-os.html). Runs Adobe's processor instead of Apple's.